# DataForm doesn't work in Silverlight 5

Tags: silverlight-toolkit, dataform, silverlight-5.0

Reproduction:

1. Create a Silverlight project
2. Turn it to version 5
3. Add references to the Silverlight Toolkit (using NuGet or direct)
4. Add a DataForm to your page
5. This is the exception the DataForm constructor throws:
   `{System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Controls.Data.Input, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   [IO.FileName_Name]
   Arguments: System.Windows.Controls.Data.Input, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
   Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=5.0.60401.00&File=mscorlib.dll&Key=IO.FileName_Name
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataForm..ctor()}`
6. Turn back to Silverlight 4
7. Now everything is cool again

Weird note: it does work in the VS/Exp. Blend 5 designers

Any ideas?? Workaround???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a very strange workaround: After I returned the SL version to 4, and re-returned it to 5, everything works! (?!?)

**Anyway** I'm sure recompiling the source-code of the SL TK targeting SL5 will help anyway.

Comment: Same nature of problem for me but this solution don't work, however if i use System.Windows.Controls.Data.DataForm.Toolkit.dll built for silverlight 4 dataform work, but as soon as change that to System.Windows.Controls.Data.DataForm.Toolkit for silverlight 5 build it again stops working. Have you faced similar problem?

Comment: @webKite that's interesting. Perhaps post a workitem on the latest release.

Answer (score 0):

I could not resolve this problem, also taking a project that was SL version 4 then migrating to SL version 5 and trying to add a DataForm.  Even though I referenced the December 2011 Silverlight 5 Toolkit, and I added a proper reference to the SL5 DataForm, because of the presence of SL version 4 assemblies I get an error.

Not sure how you can 're-return' and 'return' as suggested in the workaround but for now I think anybody migrating from SL 4 to SL5 and trying to add a dataform will experience this problem.  Best to either start from a completely new SL5 project, or, forget about using dataform with a SL4 solution migrated to SL5?